# How do I show the user the specific http response code & message using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, api, error-handling, react-hooks

I am using an API to get info & I would like to show user specific error message and code when there is an error. Specifically, with this project if I do too many requests too quick I get a `429: Too many requests`.

I would like to show this to the user but when I console.log the error I am getting something different than the response code. I get `Syntax error: < at 0 JSON position`.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps the api you are using should change its response type based on the status code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm really sure of is that your server returns some HTML layout in the response. And you try to parse it as JSON string via data.json() and of course, you get the syntax error since it's not JSON (HTML layout starts with < symbol hence the error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <) - Same Error like yours.

You can get the status code and error message like below.

```
fetch(API).then((response) => {
    console.log('status code', response.status)
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('error msg', error.message)
})
```